# Microsoft Azure + SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, windows, azure, azure-sql-database

How can i create a SQL Server 2008 SQL Database with microsoft azure.

Looks like it is defaulted to 
productversion :  11.0.9214.43
productlevel  : RTM
edition : SQL Azure

Please help me

Comment: Can't you just get a Windows Server VM and download SQL Server 2008 and install it in that VM?

Comment: Are you trying to do so on a Windows Azure SQL Database instance __or__ a VM set up with SQL Server?  If its the former you are limited to the SQL Azure "flavour" of SQL Server due to the limitations of the PaaS. [See this link for an overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336245.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to do in Virtual SQL DB in manage.windowsazure.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Azure is a cloud service version of SQL Server. You can't opt to use different versions of it (and it's actually slightly different to the regular server hosted version of SQL Server)

If you need a specific version of SQL Server hosted in Azure, you'll need to create a Virtual Machine and run it there.

Have a look through the VM Gallery to see if they have a pre-built VM Image with SQL 2008 installed,

Alternatively, spin up a Vanilla Window Server VM, and install SQL Server yourself.